# constraintlayout app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1 does not scale the image and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

```
<com.org.mycustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivLogo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent
       ***** app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1 *****
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

i want the image to be 59dp height but the width can be what it wants as long as it maintains the aspect ratio.  so i thought of doing layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1  which says to adjust the width all you want such that there is a 1:1 (square) ratio. but my image is still stretched. if i use         android:scaleType="centerInside" instead then everything gets resolved. what am i doing wrong.

Comment: By 1:1, you want square ?

Comment: Try make width also `59dp` and scaleType="center"

Comment: i wanted to use app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio for it ..thats the key. i wanted to see how this would workd if using constrant dimension. and yes i want a square that is 59dp by 59dp